# Scrapy - Downloader middleware not being loaded?

Tags: python, scrapy, middleware

I've been trying to enable Downloader middleware in my scrapy project but it doesn't seem like it is being recognized at all. I have installed some third party middleware and I cannot tell if it is being used or not. I have even tried uninstalling the middleware packages and running my code and it runs without raising any error saying that the package does not exist or anything hence the confusion.

Everything in my settings.py is being used properly like other settings and parameters are showing up normally as they are defined in settings.py, but it just feels like downloader middleware is not working at all.

This is the downloader_middleware code in my settings.py file

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARE = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 110, #installed with pip
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': 190,
    'scrapy_proxies.RandomProxy': 200, #installed with pip
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 210,
}
```

Here is my log when I run scrapy crawl spider:

```
2017-07-06 12:46:20 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
```

it seems like the downlaoder_middleware code is just being ignored as UserAgentMiddleware is being enabled anyways regardless of other third part middleware that I installed.

Also I have tried using custom settings in my spider.py like this (the custom pipeline did work as intended) but the same things happened regardless if I had the custom settings or not:

```
custom_settings = {
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
            'someCustomPipeline': 300,
        },

        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARE': {
            'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
            'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 110, #installed with pip
            'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': 190,
            'scrapy_proxies.RandomProxy': 200, #installed with pip
            'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 210,
        }
    }
```

Comment: The setting is called [`DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#std:setting-DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES), with an "S" at the end.

Comment: I can't believe I spent all this time trying to figure out what the heck is going on and I couldn't spot that, thanks!

Comment: I have something of a similar issue in custom_settings for a spider. Can you have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73554300/scrapy-avoiding-few-settings-defined-in-custom-settings-for-a-spider

Answer (score 0):

To disable all default middleware, the docs says that you should set all middlewares found in `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES_BASE` to `None` explicitly in your `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARE`. as is said in the docs [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#topics-downloader-middleware)?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, aren't downloader middlewares a completely different thing to spider middlewares?

Comment: yeah i realized that. sorry deleting this answer.