# Scrapy avoiding few settings defined in custom settings for a spider

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using custom settings for scrapy spiders and few settings are getting avoided while running the spider. Most importantly `'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES'`

Below is the spider custom settings

```
custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {'app.sitescrapper.sitescrapper.middlewares.RotateUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
                                   'app.sitescrapper.sitescrapper.middlewares.ProjectDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
                                   'app.sitescrapper.sitescrapper.selenium_middlewares.SeleniumMiddleware': 123,
                                    },
        'COOKIES_ENABLED': False,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 6,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 2,
        'CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD' : 1,
        'TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED' : False,
        'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED' : True,
        'LOG_LEVEL' : 'WARNING',
        # Duplicates pipeline
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'app.sitescrapper.sitescrapper.pipelines.DuplicatesPipeline': 300},
    }
```

From the log the following settings are overridden

```
Overridden settings:
{'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED': True,
'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 6,
'COOKIES_ENABLED': False,
'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 2,
'LOG_LEVEL': 'WARNING',
'TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED': False}
```

pipelines are also executing well. How `'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES'` can be activated ?

**Update**

```
@celery.task(name='CeleryTask.crawl')
def scrape(baseURL):
    crawl_data = [baseURL]
    def run_process():
        process = CrawlerProcess()
        process.crawl(myCrawler,category=crawl_data)
        process.start()
    p = p1(target=run_process)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

The spiders are run as celery asynchronous job and not from command line. When the spider is executed from CLI, middlewares are activated.

**Update 2**

From CLI

If using `scrapy runspider file_name.py`, then middleware in the custom settings are activated.
But using `scrapy crawl spider_name` the middleware in the custom settings are not activated.

Comment: Once I saw a dev running the spider by calling `scrapy runspider x`. Check that you are not doing that. Spiders that are part of project should be run as `scrapy crawl x`.

Comment: @Upendra Thanks for replying. I added an update section to the question. I am still stuck there and still couldnt sort the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings listed in `Overridden settings`:
 cover only settings in [/scrapy/settings/default_settings.py](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/2.6.2/scrapy/settings/default_settings.py) - only settings from scrapy (doesn't cover settings from third party modules)
and settings which values are not dictionary ([code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/5862f6b8e1cd9e240c4b3e79f2eddd0b9f33ef8c/scrapy/settings/__init__.py#L489-L501)) - middlewares will not listed here.

In order to make check for custom `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES`, `SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES`, `ITEM_PIPELINES` or `EXTENSIONS` it is required to check log entries (it's right after `overridden settings` log entry:

 `[scrapy.middleware] Enabled extensions:...`
`[scrapy.middleware] Enabled downloader middlewares:`
`[scrapy.middleware] Enabled spider middlewares:` 
`[scrapy.middleware] Enabled item pipelines:` 
If custom middlewares connected corretly - custom middlewares will be in list. (If not - it's probably path issue)